# Read values from a running program

Tags: c++, python, c, windows, io

In a DOS `.exe` program (with no access to source code), the DOS screen says: `rate = 60.` (or some other value).

How do I read the output "60" to use as input to an application I'm making in Python or C/C++,
other than by reading and typing it (I want to run it dozens of times).

This program runs in Windows XP mode.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module. There are a few different ways; the most general is to use a `Popen` object.

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> proc = subprocess.Popen(['echo', 'rate = 60'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                                   stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
                                                   stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> proc.communicate()
('rate = 60\n', '')
```

If you're running Python 2.7 or higher, then you could also use [`subprocess.check_output`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).

Comment: As [RanRag](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8964406/577088)'s post illustrates, the `shlex` module can be useful for breaking a command line into a correctly parsed list for input into the `Popen` constructor.

Answer (score 2):

In python:

```
import commands
commands.getoutput(cmd)
```

http://docs.python.org/library/commands.html#commands.getoutput

Comment: "[Deprecated since version 2.6: The commands module has been removed in Python 3.0. Use the subprocess module instead.](http://docs.python.org/library/commands.html#module-commands)"

Comment: @senderle, thank you, then let the answer with subprocess mark as correct!

Answer (score 1):

Try [Subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module to run `dos.exe` program from python code.

```
import shlex
cmdline = "command to execute your exe file"
cmd = shlex.split(cmdline)
output_process = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pipe.
`prgm.exe | anotherprogram.exe`
Just remember that the anotherprogram will get the whole output of prgm.exe

Answer (score 0):

You can also invoke the application from your app and store the return value using [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).